# Find sum of absolute difference

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

Given array of integers A and B. For each item in B, find the sum of absolute difference with A elements and build the result array.

**Example:**

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [3,2,1,5]
```

**Result = ** `[3,2,3,9]`

**Explanation:**

```
For i=0
B[0] = 3
sum of absolute difference with A is (3-1) + (3-2) + (3-3) = (2+1+0) = 3

For i=1
B[1] = 2
sum of absolute difference with A is (2-1) + (2-2) + (2-3) = (1+0+1) = 2

For i=2
B[2] = 1
sum of absolute difference with A is (1-1) + (1-2) + (1-3) = (0+1+2) = 3

For i=3
B[3] = 5
sum of absolute difference with A is (5-1) + (5-2) + (5-3) = (4+3+2) = 9

So result = [3,2,3,9]
```

Here is my code:
I used a hashmap to avoid re-calculating values if already calculated.

```
static  List<Long> solve(int[] A, int[] B) {
    List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Integer, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int b: B) {
        long sum = 0;
        if(map.get(b) != null) {
            result.add(map.get(b));
        } else {
            for(int a : A) {
                sum += Math.abs(b - a);
            }
            map.put(b, sum);
            result.add(sum);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

My code complexity is O(m*n) where m is size of array A and n is size of array B.

How to reduce time complexity of my code.

Comment: Could you check the expected result of `i = 2`? I believe it should be 3 instead of 5.

Comment: Does this problem have a web page?  It could be a programming challenge / practice site, for example.  If it does, it would be polite to include a link to the web page.

Comment: If your code works, it might be a better question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) . Check out their Tour and Help Center.

Comment: @Old Dog, that seems to me a close call. The OP is here to improve the algorithm, not the code. Whereas Code Review might make suggestions for improving the algorithm, my understanding it that their reason for being is mainly to Review Code. (CR is certainly an excellent corner of SO.)

Comment: "Reduce complexity": sort A, and compute cumulative means for A both from the left and right (m log m). For each b in B, binary search to find the position in A where it switches from a <= b to a > b; log m. Now the abs sum is `(b - mean(where a <= b)) * len(where a <= b) + (mean(where b > a) - b) * len(where b > a)`. This is O(m log(m) + n log(m)), but I'm not in the mood to write the full code. Lots of off-by-ones and edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is "how to reduce time complexity", I'll sketch out an algorithm for that without code. For actual code improvement, I think [Elliott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78064449/7543069) is simpler and, unless you really need speed for large inputs, generally better.

1. Sort A: `A = [1, 2, 3]`.
2. Compute cumulative means from the left and right: `mA_left = [1, 1.5, 2], mA_right = [2, 2.5, 3]`. `mA_left[1]` means "The mean of the items in A to the left of (including) index 1". `mA_right[1]` means "The mean of the items in A to the right of (including) index 1".

For each `b` in `B`:

1. Binary search to find the index where `b` would fit in `A`. If `b` = 2, then our index would be `i=1`. If there's multiple instances of `b` then choose a side to prefer (e.g. always the last match in the list).
2. Now `mA_right[i+1]` is the mean of every item in A that's > b, and `mA_left[i]` is the mean of every item in A that's <= b.
3. The abs sum for `b` on the left is `(b - mA_left[i]) * (i + 1)` (for `b=2`: `(2 - 1.5) * 2 == 1`). On the right it's `(mA_right[i+1] - b) * (A.length() - i - 1)` (for `b=2`: `(3 - 2) * 1`). You may need to add some extra handling at the edges of either of the lists. Adding these together, in our example this correctly gives us the total abs sum of 2.

This results in a final complexity of O(m log m) for sorting the list, plus O(n log m) for a binary search on A for each element of B. That gives us O(m log m + n log m).

---

For completeness (inspired by @Cary Swoveland's answer), here's a Python implementation as well, although we both seem to be in the position of knowing other languages far better than we do Java.

```py
import bisect
import itertools

def bisect_abs_sum(A: list[int], B: list[int]):
    A.sort()

    # Cumulative sums ascending and descending
    # Not using means to avoid floating point -- division is canceled out in abs_sum computation
    cm_asc = list(itertools.accumulate(A))
    cm_dsc = list(itertools.accumulate(reversed(A)))[::-1]

    result = []
    for b in B:
        i = bisect.bisect_right(A, b)  # A[:i] <= b, A[i:] > b
        lte_sum = cm_asc[i - 1] if i > 0 else 0
        gt_sum = cm_dsc[i] if i < len(A) else 0
        abs_sum = (b * i - lte_sum) + (gt_sum - b * (len(A) - i))
        result.append(abs_sum)

    return result
```

Comment: Or since we're sorting integers, maybe a radix sort for O(m + n log m) works too ;)

Answer (score 2):

I see that while I was working on my answer @ExaltedToast posted an answer that uses the same approach as mine. I will leave mine up, however, as I have provided more detail plus working code.

It will be shown that the computational complexity of the algorithm proposed is O(`bs * ln(as)`), where `bs` is the size of array `b` and `as` is the size of array `a`, provided `as` not substantially larger `bs`, in which case it would be O(`as`).

As I don't know Java I have used Ruby, which, with a bit of explanation, can be viewed as pseudo-code. Even where the coding is opaque, the arguments and return values for the various methods should make it clear what the gears are doing.

**Background**

- I assume the array a is sorted
- e is an element of b in the following

We wish to compute

Σ<sub>i</sub>|e-a<sub>i</sub>|

which can be written

Σ<sub>i in le</sub>e-a<sub>i</sub> + Σ<sub>i in gt</sub>a<sub>i</sub>-e

where

- le is the set of indices i of a for which a<sub>i</sub> ≤ e
- gt is the set of indices i of a for which a<sub>i</sub> > e

The above expression reduces to

(nle-ngt)*e + Σ<sub>i in gt</sub>a<sub>i</sub> - Σ<sub>i in le</sub>a<sub>i</sub>

which can be expressed

(2*nle-n)*e + Σ<sub>i in gt</sub>a<sub>i</sub> - Σ<sub>i in le</sub>a<sub>i</sub>

where

- nle is the size of le
- ngt is the size of gt
- n is the size of a

Note that

nle-ngt = nle-(n-nle) = 2*nlt-n

**An Example**

Suppose, after sorting,

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Next, create the following hash (aka hashmap, dictionary).

```
h = { 0=>20, 1=>16, 2=>8, 3=>-4, 4=>-20 }
```

Each key but the last is an index of `a`. Suppose an element of `b` equals `3`. Then `i = 1` is the smallest index of `a` for which `3 <= a[i]`. `h[1] #=> 16` then equals the sum of the elements of `a` that are greater than `3` (`4+6+8=18`) less the sum of the elements of `a` that are less than or equal to `3` (only `2`), or `18-2=16`.

By performing a binary search on `a` (one that returns an index of the element located) we see that for `e = 3` `i = 1` is the smallest index for which `a[i] > e`. Then

```
n = a.size #=> 4
nle = i #=> 1
```

The sum of absolute differences between `e = 3` and the elements of `a` therefore equals

```
(2*nle-n)*e + h[i]
  #=> (2*i-n)*e + h[1] => (2*1-4)*3 + 16 => 10
```

We can check this result:

```
a.sum { |n| (n-3).abs } #=> 10
```

Now suppose `e = 9`. Then a binary search of `a` would find no element of `a` that is greater than `9` so the index of the first element of `a` greater than `9` is set to

```
i = a.size #=> 4
```

Since, as always, `nle = i`, the sum of the absolute differences for `e = 9` equals

```
(2*i-n)*e + h[i]
  #=> (2*4-4)*9 + -20 => 16
```

which we may confirm is correct.

```
a.sum { |n| (n-9).abs } #=> 16
```

**Ruby code**

There are two helper methods, the first of which constructs the hash `h` in the above example.

```
def create_hash(a)
  # create an empty hash
  h = {}
  a.each_index do |i|
    h[i] =
    case i
    when 0
      # for elements of b less than all elements of a h[0] equals the
      # sum of all elements of a
      a.sum
    else
      # compute h[i] from h[i-1]. a[i-1] was included in h[i-1]'s greater
      # than sum but now is included in h[i-1]'s less than or equal
      # sum so h[i] = h[i-1] - a[i-1] + (-a[i-1])= h[i-1] - 2*a[i-1]
      h[i-1] - 2*a[i-1]
    end
  end
  # for elements of b greater than all elements of a h[a.size] equals
  # the negative of the sum of all elements of a
  h[a.size] = -h[0]
  # return h
  h
end
```

Try it.

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8]
create_hash(a)
  #=> { 0=>20, 1=>16, 2=>8, 3=>-4, 4=>-20 }
```

---

The following method returns the smallest index `i` of `a` for which `a[i] > e`.<sup>1</sup>

```
def first_gt_index(a, e)
  a.bsearch_index { |n| n > e } || a.size
end
```

Try it.

```
first_gt_index(a, 1) #=> 0
first_gt_index(a, 2) #=> 1
first_gt_index(a, 3) #=> 1
first_gt_index(a, 4) #=> 2
first_gt_index(a, 5) #=> 2
first_gt_index(a, 9) #=> 4
```

---

Lastly, the main method.

```
def sum_of_abs_diffs(a, b)
  n = a.size
  a_sorted = a.sort
  h = create_hash(a_sorted)
  b.sum do |e|
    i = first_gt_index(a_sorted, e)
    # compute and add to the total the sum of absolute
    # differences between e and the elements of a
    (2*i-n)*e + h[i]
  end
  # The last value computed, the sum of the absolute differences
  # between all elements of b and the elements of a, is returned
ends
```

**Illustrative Examples**

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
sum_of_abs_diffs(a, [3, 2, 1, 5])         #=> 17

a = [2, 4, 6, 8]
sum_of_abs_diffs(a, [3])                  #=> 10
sum_of_abs_diffs(a, [9])                  #=> 16
sum_of_abs_diffs(a, [-3])                 #=> 32
sum_of_abs_diffs(a, [4, 7, 2, 9, 8, -3])  #=> 90
```

---

The time complexity is O(`a.size`) to construct the hash and (close to)  O(`b.size * ln(a.size)`), where `ln(a.size)` is for executing the binary search. I say "close to" because hash lookups are not quite constant time.

<sup>1 `a.bsearch_index { |n| n > e }` returns `nil` if no element of `a` is greater than `e`. The expression therefore becomes `nil || a.size`, which returns `a.size` (`||` denotes logical or). See [Array#bsearch_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index) and [Array#bsearch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch).</sup>

Comment: Good work on actually proving it works, I was just messing with Python and unit tests until something worked, haha

Comment: Although similar I think this is the better solution because it doesn't require floating point numbers which can cause troubles in many languages due to rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would *simplify*. You don't need a `Map`, and you should probably return an `int[]`. Given a value `v` and an array `A` you find the absolute difference with a loop like

```
private static int absDiff(int[] A, int v) {
    int r = 0;
    for (int i : A) {
        r += Math.abs(v - i);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Then you can use that to populate a result array like

```
public static int[] solve(int[] A, int[] B) {
    int[] result = new int[B.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        result[i] = absDiff(A, B[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And test it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] B = { 3, 2, 1, 5 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(solve(A, B)));
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
[3, 2, 3, 9]
```

Comment: I need a solution that runs in less time, I added Map to just skip some calculation that is already done in previous iterations. Even this answer runs in O(m*n) so I am curious to know how this solves my question.